# ArrayList remove methods

Tags: java, arraylist

```
private List <Integer> nums;

public void numQuest()
{
    int k = 0;
    Integer zero = new Integer(0);
    while(k < nums.size())
    {
       if(nums.get(k).equals(zero))
          nums.remove(k);

       k++
    }
}
```

List nums contains the following value [0, 0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]

I executed numQuest and nums became [0, 4, 2, 5, 3] but can someone explain why?

I thought the code removed all the zeroes so why is there still a zero in nums?????

Comment: Run the code and find out?

Comment: you can just execute the code.. why ask here ?

Comment: Well i actually did the correct answer is [0, 4, 2, 5, 3] but I don't know why because shouldn't all the zeroes be removed?

Comment: What does remove do to the underlying list? What does k hold?

Comment: the remove method removes the value in nums at position k

Comment: What happens to position k after removal?

Comment: it increments by one but i think it should still run through all the positions of nums...so shouldnt all the zeroes be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the 0's will not be removed (which is your intention).

After the first iteration, your list will be `[0, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 0]`.
Now, `k=1`. You will only be looking from the element `4` at index = 1.

Instead, try using Iterators:

Example:

```
for (Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  String s = iter.next();
  if (s.equals("to_remove")) {
    iter.remove();
  }
}
```